# Pandas: Flatten Nested Dictionary vertically

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary as below:

```
[{'name': 'jack', 'tagList': [{'tagId': '10', 'tagName': 'AB'},{'tagId': '20', 
'tagName': 'BC'}]}, 
 {'name': 'mike', 'tagList': [{'tagId': '30', 'tagName': 'DE'},{'tagId': '40', 
'tagName': 'FG'}]}]
```

I want to turn this into a dataframe like below:

```
Name   tagList_tagID   tagList_tagName      
Jack        10               AB
Jack        20               BC
mike        30               DE
mike        40               FG
```

How can I convert this list of dictionaries to pandas dataframe in an efficient way.

Answer (score 3):

Try with [`json.normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
lst = [{'name': 'jack', 'tagList': [{'tagId': '10', 'tagName': 'AB'},
                                    {'tagId': '20', 'tagName': 'BC'}]}, 
       {'name': 'mike', 'tagList': [{'tagId': '30', 'tagName': 'DE'},
                                    {'tagId': '40', 'tagName': 'FG'}]}]

df = pd.json_normalize(lst, record_path="tagList", meta=["name"])

#formatting to match expected output
df = df.set_index("name").add_prefix("tagList_")

>>> df
     tagList_tagId tagList_tagName
name                              
jack            10              AB
jack            20              BC
mike            30              DE
mike            40              FG
```